# Padding Zeros in XSLT

Tags: xslt, padding

Is there any function that pads zeros on the left?

The requirements of what I'm trying to do are:

- We don't know the coming input string length.
- If it is less than 20 we have to pad zeros on the left side.
- If the input string length is 10 then we have to pad 10 zeros in the left side.

### Example

Input:

> 1234567899

Output:

> 00000000001234567899

Answer (score 29, accepted):

format-number function can be used for this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(1234567899, '00000000000000000000')" />
```

Comment: You must swap the `'` symbol and the `"` symbols, like this:
`select="format-number(1234567899, '00000000000000000000')"`

Comment: @Jens Kloster I think you're wrong about that.  It works both ways for me.  What's your source for that?

Comment: @AdamMackler I found it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256225(v=vs.110).aspx), but it appears that both ways are correct.

Comment: If you want to decide the padding length at run-time, you can hack this by using way too many zeros and calling it like `format-number(12345, substring('00000000000000000000000000',1,$paddingLength))`.